# Reference columns dynamically inside mutate() with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create columns using `summarise()` based on column names that are dynamic. I find that I can easily create dynamic names with glue syntax `"{}"` and `:=`, but I cannot figure out how to reference these columns inside another `mutate()` function.

Based on the tips I read online, the common solution is to use `{{varname}}` or to use `varname_enq <- enquo(varname)` with `!!varname_enq`. Neither of those two approaches has worked for me, unfortunately.

So far I have had a look at other SO posts as well as the [Programming with dplyr guide](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). I greatly appreciate all the advice you can give me!

Below is a small example that highlights the problem.

```
This is the goal:

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Species    species_sum cumulative_sum
  <fct>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 setosa            250.           250.
2 versicolor        297.           547.
3 virginica         329.           876.
```

```
mycol <- "species_sum"
mycol_enquo <- enquo(mycol)
myothercol <- "cumulative_sum"

# this works, but the cumulative sum isn't dynamic
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise("{mycol}" := sum(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cumulative_sum = cumsum(species_sum))

# this works, but the cumsum function still uses a fixed variable name
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise("{mycol}" := sum(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate("{myothercol}" := cumsum(species_sum))

# doesn't work, the new column is all NA
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise("{mycol}" := sum(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate("{myothercol}" := cumsum( "{mycol}" ))
  
# doesn't work, the new column is all NA
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise("{mycol}" := sum(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate("{myothercol}" := cumsum( {{mycol}} ))

# doesn't work, the new column is all NA
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise("{mycol}" := sum(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate("{myothercol}" := cumsum( !!mycol_enquo ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

To specify a variable with a character vector, `.data` is your friend.

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(!!mycol := sum(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(!!myothercol := cumsum(.data[[mycol]]))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    species_sum cumulative_sum
  <fct>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 setosa            250.           250.
2 versicolor        297.           547.
3 virginica         329.           876.
```

Alternatively you can utilise `across()`

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(Sepal.Length, sum, .names = mycol)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(mycol), cumsum, .names = myothercol))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    species_sum cumulative_sum
  <fct>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 setosa            250.           250.
2 versicolor        297.           547.
3 virginica         329.           876
```

Comment: Nice, this does just what I want! To go a bit further, (1) is `!!mycol :=` the same as `"{mycol}" :=` or are there any important differences worth knowing (aside from the fact that you can write more things inside `""`)? (2) Do you know (and if you do, could you perhaps elaborate on) why neither `"{mycol}"` nor `!!mycol_enquo` worked here? Programming with NSE is still quite tricky for me, so I appreciate any knowledge you can share!

Comment: The `!!mycol :=` used to be the canonical tidy method, but they've recently changed it to utilise the `"{mycol}" :=` method and are both basically the same thing. You can also wrap a data variable in double curly braces, e.g.`"{{mycol}}" :=` which then takes the name of the data variable., hence the distinction.
I'm not sure of the specifics as to why it didn't work and would have to dig a bit deeper, but for me personally, some trial and error is what usually works.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)

myFunction <- function(df, col1, col2) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise({{ col1 }} := sum(Sepal.Length))  %>% 
     ungroup() %>%
     mutate({{ col2 }} := cumsum({{ col1 }}))
}

iris %>% myFunction(species_sum, cumulative_sum)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Species    species_sum cumulative_sum
  <fct>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 setosa            250.           250.
2 versicolor        297.           547.
3 virginica         329.           876.
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the job, but it requires that I first wrap the code in a function, which in my concrete use case is not really desirable.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `sym()` that will convert the string to a symbol and thereafter we use `!!` to unquote.
Note in contrast to `{{` we have to use `"`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

my_function <- function(df, mycol, myothercol) {
  df %>% 
  summarise(!!mycol := sum(Sepal.Length), .by = Species) %>% 
  mutate(!!myothercol := cumsum(!!sym(mycol)))
}

iris %>% 
  my_function("species_sum", "cumulative_sum")
```

```
    Species species_sum cumulative_sum
1     setosa       250.3          250.3
2 versicolor       296.8          547.1
3  virginica       329.4          876.5
```

Comment: A very nice solution, I didn't know about `sym()`, thank you! This apparently also works outside a function, unlike `{{}}` it seems.